# Installation of redmine with bundler requires root password

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation, rake, redmine

I'm trying to install redmine on my CentOS 6.3 server. I created an user to run the program, then I tried to install it with the command

```
bundle install --without development test postgresql sqlite rmagick
```

but it asks me the password

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system:

Interrupt: An error occurred while installing rake (10.0.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

The gem list currently installed is:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.1.0)
bundler (1.2.3)
charlock_holmes (0.6.9)
io-console (0.4.1, 0.3)
json (1.7.6, 1.5.4)
minitest (4.6.0, 2.5.1)
rake (10.0.3, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12.1, 3.9.5)
```

I'm not using RVM. As you can see these gems are available for all users: if I try to execute the gem list command for my redmine user and my root user I get the same result. The rake is alredy installed so I don't understand what's the problem: installing GitLab didn't ask me any password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install them in local folder using:

```
bundle install --without development test postgresql sqlite rmagick --path vendor/bundler
```